# An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (4A300238) Google Play console error while uploading aab file

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

1. I Am unable to upload an aab file into the Play console, ​getting an error ("An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (4A300238)").
2. Even I Am unable to upload into Internal Testing as well (An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (780DE17A)). Then aab file got uploaded but the version code is not showing. "Available to internal testers, No version codes".

I tried in multiple browsers & cleared the cache as well and tried still no luck.

We are trying from 7th Jan 2022 still facing the same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you actually tell what is the error really? `("An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (4A300238)").` tell us nothing about the problem that you're facing.

Comment: @SagarBalyan I Am unable to upload an aab file into the Play console, ​getting an error ("An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (4A300238)"). This same issue was faced many times by many developers, Many SOF questions were available, I didn't get any proper solution for this.